# How to see the members of an Active Directory group in the Mail application

Tags: macos, mail.app, active-directory

I'd like to find out how to check the members of a group defined in Active Directory from the Mail application in OSX 10.8.2 (Mountain Lion).  I have my corporate AD server defined as an LDAP server, so I can use groups from it in the address fields of an email.  But I can't work out how to see who the members of a group are, to check that I'm sending email to the people I want to.

Am I missing something obvious, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it from within Mail but I use [LDapper](http://carl-bell-2.baylor.edu/~Carl_Bell/ReadMeFiles/LDapper.html) to search the AD server at work for things like the members of a group.

It works well and setting it up is easy if you already have the settings required for Mail.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, you cannot do this directly within the Mail.app on a Mac. However, you may be able to accomplish this using Directory Utility (hidden away in /System/Library/CoreServices), depending on how your system is configured. My work Mac is bound to AD and it works for me.

Open Directory Utility. Click on Directory Editor. View "Groups" in node pertaining to whatever your AD server is. You should be able to now search for the AD group you'd like to mail to. Unfold the data for "GroupMembership" and you should see the complete listing of members of this group.

I know this is a bit roundabout, but it does work.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't work for me.  I don't see the AD server in the list of nodes, just "/Contacts", "/Local/Default" and "/Search".  When you say your Mac is "bound" to AD, does that mean you actually joined the domain in the Users and Groups panel of the System Preferences?  I haven't got that configured: I was just using the AD as an LDAP resource.

Comment: Yes, my work Mac is joined through the Users and Groups panel of System Preferences. If you are not bound in this method, I'm not sure that you will have the ability to lookup the underlying AD groups anywhere.